# Getting error while subtracting two dates(inconsistent datatypes: expected char got date)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query in which I am subtracting two dates but I am getting error. Here is the query

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.", 
       CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "Business Unit",
       ...,
       :endDate - LOSA_APP_Z.li_dt AS "Day Count",.
       ...
 from losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN code_branch CODE_BRANCH
   ON LOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
....
where LOSA_APP.app_status='A'; -- Application Status in {‘accepted’}
```

But I am getting error that

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:endDate` bind variable is the cause of the error. Try to explicitly convert `:endDate` value to a value of date datatype using `to_date` function. For example:

```
 ....

 to_date(:endDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - LOSA_APP_Z.li_dt AS "Day Count",

 ....
```